# php code not working inside html file, .htaccess configured,dreamweaver php server setted, using xampp

Tags: php, html, .htaccess, xampp, dreamweaver

I am not able to run a php script on an html file, as the picture showed in the link, it always show error and nothing function in html file.

But I already have .htaccess configured in website root, and my dreamweaver have a php local server, and I set up my php by using xamppp. I have no idea why it won't work.

My .htaccess file:

AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .html .htm

AddType application/x-httpd-php5 .php5

AddType application/x-httpd-php5 .phps

AddType application/x-httpd-php5 .html .htm

[Picture here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nDdZ5.png)

Comment: what the extention of the file name

Comment: @arif_suhail_123 index.html, do you mean this?

Comment: may be, in order for php code to run, you need php extention. in the file name

Comment: @arif_suhail_123 yes, I know that is a way to do it, if nothing can help, I would use extention php eventually. but before that, i hope to solve this and keep my html extention

Comment: if you want to solve it like this, you need to rewrite php, so in my view solve it by using php extention, its lot easier

Comment: @arif_suhail_123 I guess I have to change it all my files to php extention in order to make this work.  Thank u. I have the solution now, still wanna know why .htaccess way won't work

Answer (score 0):

Exactly what @arif_suhail_123 said. Rename the index.html file to index.php and the PHP code should be executed.
Apache does not know the file contains PHP code if the .php file extension is not present.